# FOSUserbundle access control

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-control

Hi i got an problem with my access control in symfony 2.

I want to secure the whole site except of the "/" route cause there is the login. So every route else, for example "/hello" must be secured and redirect to / if there is no user logged in.

In my security config i got this configuration:

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            login_path: /
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    ~

access_control:
     - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/.*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should it not be `- { path: ^/.+, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }` instead of `.*`?

Comment: I tried it but i still can call the /hello/test/ site

Comment: Try to invert the lines.
`access_control:
     - { path: ^/.+, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
     - { path: ^/, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Comment: The `access_control` (as with the `router`) stops at the first correct path so everything is being caught by `path: ^/` and, therefore, being authenticated anonymously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
access_control:
     - { path: ^/$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
     - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

for more info:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html